# Importing one photo into another photo?

Tags: photoshop-cs6

I am brand new to photo editing. I am trying to import a picture of my late brother into a picture of my family. Like have him very light on the side of us or behide us. Can anyone tell me a good photo editing program that I could do this with? Thank you!

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer, nor would I want anyone to consider this as self-promotion [I will clear this comment if it proves unpopular], but here are a few examples of what can be done with a little care & attention to detail in Photoshop, using the methods outlined by Corey. The backgrounds are [very obviously] not my property, these were done for a family calendar, purely for amusement, not profit. https://imgur.com/a/G1Cw1

Comment: This is not a simple process for someone new to photo editing. There are different ways of doing this, and different programs that allow you to do it. But getting a pleasing result is the difficult bit. You will have trouble finding a "one-click" solution. Consider having a professional (or at least someone with experience) do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for your loss. I've done this exact project with an image of my cousin and am most familiar with Photoshop, though other programs exist (GIMP comes to mind). Given that Adobe now offers a 1 month license through their Creative Cloud for $10 (Photography Edition for Individuals) - it's not that bad a cost to use, even if just for this one project.

The basic process is:

You'll want to load up both images once you get Photoshop open. Go to the image of your brother, select all, and copy. (CTRL + A, then CTRL + C)[On Mac, use the command key in place of ctrl]

Go to the image of your family, and paste (CTRL + V)

This will create a new Layer containing your brother on top of the layer containing your family. Make sure the top layer is selected, and add a layer mask by clicking the icon in the layer palette that looks like a circle inside a rectangle.([instructions here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html))

Mask out the portions of your brother's layer until you've got just what you need. You'll also most likely need to re-position it, maybe [transform](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/transforming-objects.html) it a bit to be smaller or larger, and maybe also adjust the [color or contrast](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-color-tone-cs6.html).

Using layer masks can be a tedious process but it does get easier as you get more practice with it.